# Unsafely treat insecure origin as secure not recognized - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, webrtc

I'm working with WebRTC on a little network. In Chrome, it doesn't work because 192.168.0.50:3000 is considered as unsecure origin.

So, I searched on google and saw everywhere that I should use `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and `--user-data-dir` flags.

However, when I use this, I have a message saying that `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` is not recognized.

Here's the command I use :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="192.168.0.50"
```

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use localhost or 127.0.0.1 and you won't have to use any flags.

Answer (score 0):

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure suggests that you need to prefix this with http, i.e. --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://192.168.0.50"